# How can I make the bot code independent of the channel,( I want a single bot code for facebook at work and DirectLine)

Tags: facebook, botframework, direct-line-botframework

**My aim is to use a single bot code to run the bot at two different channels DirectLine and Facebook@work**. I am going to cite an example of issues that I face when I am using facebook channel and directLine channel. The issues I have are the following:

The links or urls though supported through mark down in DirectLine are not supported in facebook, I have to make a seperate hero card.
Even if i use an url through hero card in facebook, the skype link cant be connected, bcos the link "sip:***@xxx.com", is changed to xxx alone.
I cannot get the name of the user from the "From.Name".

So what is the best possible way to resolve this? Should I simply write functions for each channels??Is that the only option.
What I want in the end is a bot code that is independent of the channel that is used for chatting

Comment: hi @Gp_1993 and welcome to StackOverflow. Seems the question in the title and questions in the text are different, and seems you have 2 other different problems there (The one is "sip" issue and the other is "From.Name"). This adds some confusion to answerers, probably that's why you've got downvotes. I would recommend you to clarify the question (or maybe split into different Stackoverflow questions and add more details) to make it easier for us to help you

Comment: hi @JustShadow Thanks for the reply...But the two are linked :) What I want is to know how to use the same bot framework c# code, independent of the channel that is used for chatting. So I was just citing examples of issues that are face when using two different channels ie. Directline and Facebook@work :)

Comment: as of today there is no way to generate an enriched message (more then just unformated text) for all channels with factory. you need to generate for every channel a specific response. Microsoft introduced on Build 2017 adaptive card - http://adaptivecards.io/ . its an open source approach to fix that issue by declaring an open standard for visualisation. here you can find the status of as today: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2801

Comment: Oh...ok Thank you ..You can put that as the answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark down is not supported in the Facebook channel. So there's no way to directly connect to Skype from Facebook channel.

Facebook@ work returns only the id of the corresponding user to the bot framework. We have to then use the Facebook api to get the name of the user with the corresponding id.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple switch-case for the Activity.Channel in the messagesController, then format the Activity.Text that is giving you troubles for each channel

Comment: So for each channel I have to create different herocards as well. That is how am doing right now, It looks weird, Plus the Herocards appear different ways in different channel, like according to length of text as well.